# Android camera animation on axis Z

Tags: android, animation, camera, z-axis

I'm stuck on a problem since few days and I can hardly even found someone speaking about something similar. Actually, I'm pretty confused even after a long books and articles reading, so maybe I'm just trying to kill a mosquito with a Bazooka :-), but I'm not able to find any solution around.

This is what I want to to obtain at the end:

I have a list of icons such as in the laucher, let's say disposed in a 2 rows-16 columns  matrix. When I push one of the icons, an animation should start zooming the icon pressed to full screen. Actually is not needed that the icon graphics is maintained during animation, it could even be a box enlarging from icon size to full screen.

I tried to do the job placing the icons like that (this is just a 2x4 matrix, enought to see the problem)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:paddingTop="50dp">
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView">
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_margin="5dp">
            <package.libraries.BoxX
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/boxX"
                  android:src="@drawable/icon1"
                  android:focusableInTouchMode="false" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_gravity="center"
                  android:clickable="false" android:longClickable="false"
                  android:layout_alignParentLeft="false" android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
                  android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
            <package.libraries.BoxX
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/boxX2"
                  android:src="@drawable/icon2"
                  android:focusableInTouchMode="false" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:longClickable="false" android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
                  android:layout_alignParentBottom="false" android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                  android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                  android:adjustViewBounds="false" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/boxX"
                  android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
                  android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_margin="5dp">
            <view android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  class="package.libraries.BoxX" android:id="@+id/boxX3" android:src="@drawable/icon3"
                  android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
            <view android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  class="package.libraries.BoxX" android:id="@+id/BoxX4" android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                  android:src="@drawable/icon4" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/boxX3" android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

where package.libraries.BoxX is my custom view that extend ImageView and run the animation. This is how I create and run the animation:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    XxFlipAnimator animator = new XxFlipAnimator(BoxX.this, strDrw, endDrw,
            BoxX.this.getWidth() / 2, BoxX.this.getHeight() / 2, true);
    animator.setFillAfter(true);
    animator.setFillEnabled(true);
    animator.setDuration(500);
    BoxX.this.startAnimation(animator);
    mStatus = status.CLICKED;
}
```

And the XxFlipAnimator is my animation class, derived from [this](https://code.google.com/p/myandroidwidgets/source/browse/trunk/FlipAnimatorExample/src/com/beanie/examples/animation/FlipAnimator/FlipAnimator.java), that has this ApplyTrasformation method:

```
   protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            final Matrix matrix = t.getMatrix();

    camera.save();
    camera.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, (float) (1100.0 * (0.5f - interpolatedTime)));

    if ((interpolatedTime < 0.5f) || !(zoom))
        camera.rotateY(degrees);
    camera.getMatrix(matrix);
    camera.restore();

    matrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY);
    matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);
}
```

The Zoom is obtained going negative with z-axis, and here come the first question: is this right? if this is the right way to have an icon "growing", which is the real z-axis range? I have found the constant 1100 just experimentally, but I'd rather prefere to have some spec.

The real problem, by the way, is: when I push the icon, the animation starts well, the icon dimensions start growing but when they reach the parent relative layout, they clamp. Is not something related to relative layout, as I tried to change it to Linear and the result is the same...so the point is: is it possible to have the animation going outside the dimension of the parent layout of the animating view?

Thanks a lot to anyone who will help,

Cristiano

Comment: New info: I just tried with one single LinearLayout with padding "ALL" at 50dp and one icon in the middle. The animation grows up to padded area, not to all screen. So the question is just...how to make an animation that fills all the screen at the end, no matter which is the layout containing the View to be animated? I have left the code in my original question just because, maybe, it could be usefull to someont.

Comment: Another update: tried to run the animaton on the Layout itself, the result is the same. Layout grows up to its parent limits.